# Spring Webflux, Make all request wait for queue to be replenished by first request

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am using Spring webflux and default project reactor. Each http request will poll the ConcurrentLinkedQueue and get a unique number, if the queue becomes empty all the request should wait for the queue to be populated (I am looking at smart way to refill the queue as part of the reactive chain of the first request which found queue is empty and make all the other requests wait for the queue to be replenished). I am find it hard to implement it in spring webflux and project reactor. By way, during the app startup I have event lister to populate the queue on app load. This problem will be prominent once the queue is empty. **Any help here will be much appreciated**. Here is the minified version of the code...

```
package com.learning;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.LongStream;

public class UniqueNumberGenerator {

    Queue<Long> uniqueNumberCache = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    static private Long sequence = 0l;

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws InterruptedException {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(9);

        UniqueNumberGenerator uniqueNumberGenerator = new UniqueNumberGenerator();

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            executorService.submit(() -> {
                uniqueNumberGenerator.getUniqueNumber()
                        .doOnNext(number -> System.out.println("Consumed number : " + number))
                        .subscribe();
            });
        }

        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }


    public Mono<Long> getUniqueNumber() {

        Long orderId = uniqueNumberCache.poll();

        if(orderId != null) {
            return Mono.just(orderId);
        } else {
            return generateUniqueNumbers();
        }

    }

    /**
     * This is where the problem lies, When the queue is empty in the above method,
     * All thw thread are concurrently trying to get the db sequence and generating the
     * unique numbers and populating the queue,
     * where I want to only one thread to populate the queue and make all other to wait for it
     *
     * @return
     */

    public Mono<Long> generateUniqueNumbers() {

        Mono<Long> sequenceMono = getSequence()
                .flatMap(nextVal -> {
                    var list = LongStream.rangeClosed(1, 9)
                            .boxed()
                            .map(value -> Long.valueOf(nextVal + "" + value))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    System.out.println("Generated number " + list);
                    var nextOrderId = list.remove(0);
                    uniqueNumberCache.addAll(list);
                    return Mono.just(nextOrderId);
                });

        return sequenceMono;
    }

    /**
     * This method is actually backed by db sequence
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Mono<Long> getSequence() {
        return Mono.create(longMonoSink -> {
            synchronized (sequence) {
                sequence = sequence + 1;
                //System.out.println("sequence : " + sequence);
                longMonoSink.success(sequence);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Output

```
Generated number [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
Generated number [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
Generated number [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
Generated number [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]
Generated number [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
Consumed number : 31
Consumed number : 11
Consumed number : 21
Consumed number : 41
Consumed number : 51
Generated number [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69]
Consumed number : 61
Generated number [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79]
Consumed number : 71
Generated number [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]
Consumed number : 81
Generated number [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
Consumed number : 91
Consumed number : 17
Consumed number : 12
Consumed number : 13
Consumed number : 16
Consumed number : 14
Consumed number : 15
```

By looking at above example it is very clear that all the threads are populating the queue. There are around 90 (each thread generated 10 numbers ) unique numbers generated for 15 requests

Comment: have you tried using `map` instead of `flatMap` after your get sequence, as `map` is synchronous, while `flatMap` is async.

Comment: still the same...